# $limit and $skip as optional in MongoDB Aggregation pipeline

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a pipeline with `$facet` and using pagination inside it with `$skip` and `$limit`. I want to implement a condition when parameters are passed to skip and limit then only pagination should work else it should return me all the records.

```
Model.aggregate([
    {
      $facet: {
        comments: [
          {
            $match: { issueId: Types.ObjectId(issueId) },
          },
          {
            $skip: skip,
          },
          {
            $limit: parseInt(size, 10),
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: 'users',
              localField: 'createdBy',
              foreignField: '_id',
              as: 'commentedBy',
            },
          },
        ]
      }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try separating all pipeline on the base of condition,

```
let pagination = true; // true for add, false for remove 
// initialise default comments array
let comments = [];

// set match stage
comments.push({  $match: { issueId: Types.ObjectId(issueId) } });

// if pagination is required, put you condition to enable disable pagination
if (pagination === true) {
  comments.push({ $skip: skip });
  comments.push({ $limit: parseInt(size, 10) });
}

// lookup
comments.push({
  $lookup: {
    from: 'users',
    localField: 'createdBy',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'commentedBy',
  },
});

// execute query
Model.aggregate([{ $facet: { comments: comments } }]);
```

---

Second option using concat array function [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat),

```
let pagination = true; // true for add, false for remove 
Model.aggregate([
  { 
    $facet: Array.prototype.concat(
      [{  $match: { issueId: Types.ObjectId(issueId) } }],
      ( 
        pagination == true ? [{ $skip: skip }, { $limit: parseInt(size, 10) }] : []
      ),
      [{
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'createdBy',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'commentedBy',
        }
      }]
    )
  }
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for it, got it. It will be a bit long task if you have a very long pipeline. I was looking for something from MongoDB's side where I can mark these two as optional.

Comment: they are not providing any option to disable/optional any pipeline stage, if you don't want to use any pipeline stage then don't pass pipeline stage in aggregation, simple.

Comment: added second option as well if you want to use inline query.

Comment: thank-you, the second one sounds more promising to me in my case. I will try it.